# Centos8: Selinux blocking Samba service from starting

Tags: selinux, samba4, centos8

My Samba4 service is being blocked from starting using systemctl. The audit log shows:

```
type=AVC msg=audit(1606428851.446:87): avc:  denied  { execute } for  pid=1748 comm="(samba)" 
name="samba" dev="dm-0" ino=1462831 scontext=system_u:system_r:init_t:s0 
tcontext=unconfined_u:object_r:user_home_t:s0 tclass=file permissive=0
```

Setting Selinux policy to "permissive" solves the problem .... but it's not a full time solution.

Samba was built locally. It's not a repo package.
So as I understand I have to manually enable it's executable path in Selinux. But how can I do it?

Service definition file looks like:

```
[Unit]
Description=Samba Active Directory Domain Controller
After=network.target remote-fs.target nss-lookup.target

[Service]
Type=forking
ExecStart=/usr/local/samba/sbin/samba -D
PIDFile=/usr/local/samba/var/run/samba.pid
ExecReload=/bin/kill -HUP $MAINPID

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to manually compiling Samba (why??!?) you also moved instead of copied the binary into place in `/usr/local`. Thus it kept its SELinux type `user_home_t`, applied to files in user home directories.

A simple `restorecon` will fix that.

Of course, since you manually built Samba (again, WHY?) many of its other files will be in locations SELinux does not expect, so you likely will have further issues.

Comment: I build it as for time of Centos8 install there was no samba4 package for Centos8. Now it sems there is one ... No I did't move anything anywhere. If you would ever build a software you would now there are config files prepared by the devs to put executables in proper folders. Building does not  mean to create by hand! . Will test your solution anyway.

Comment: @PaulPaku Eh? Samba 4 has been in CentOS 8 since day one. It's called `samba`, not `samba4` though.

Comment: Sure, I am blind .. As I remember there was no Samba at all at the day I downloaded ISO.

Comment: Tried to use samba package on other server... not working. Will have to build it myself :( Look my last question.